# python modulo operation for basic mathematics operation

Tags: python, modulo

can someone please explain how does the module of 14%40 is 14 in python programming language? check below :

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 14/40
0.35
>>> 14%40
14
>>>
```

Comment: ... what did you expect it to be?

Comment: I2 i Guess. I know it is wrong so if possible explain me . thanks

Comment: l2??? What? read the duplicate question. It is explained in there.

Comment: I assume you meant `12` not `I2`. Do you think it should be 12 because 14*2 + 12 == 40 ? That's not what the modulo operation does. In fact, `40 % 14 == 12`

Comment: Can you please explain to me? how does the answer is 14?

Comment: `14 % 40 == 14` because 40 divides into 14 zero times, with remainder 14, in other words, `14 == 0 * 40 + 14`.